# Connect to Cassandra Apache with SSL using cassandra-driver in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra

I try connect to my Cassandra but I have probably wrongly configured. I run it on localhost. Cassandra has generated certificated and add on. In cqlsh there are no errors with flag --ssl. My fragment code is

```js
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = {
 key : fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
 cert : fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),
 ca : [fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem')]
};
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
  authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
  sslOptions : tls.connect(options)
 });
```

what I'm doing wrong? 
Please help!

Answer (score 6):

You must specify an `Object` instance in `sslOption` property to enable ssl on the driver.

Using your code sample:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sslOptions = {
  key : fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  cert : fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),
  ca : [fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem')]
};
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
  authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
  sslOptions : sslOptions
});
```

If you do not use client certificates, you can just use an empty object instance:

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
  authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
  sslOptions : {}
});
```

And it will use the defaults specified in the Node.js `tls` module.

Answer (score 3):

You should not need to specify `tls.connect(options)` rather you should just provide `options` for sslOptions.   The driver calls `tls.connect` with the `sslOptions` you provide.

If you make this change and still get errors, can you share with me what they are?  There are a lot of different factors that can make establishing an ssl connection fail.

Comment: Look at my post below