# How to configure sslOptions using Node.js driver for Cassandra?

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra, datastax

I'm running Cassandra 3.9.

I refered to [Connect to Cassandra Apache with SSL using cassandra-driver in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29548694/connect-to-cassandra-apache-with-ssl-using-cassandra-driver-in-node-js) before I created this post, but I couldn't solve my problem.

I followed along [this datastax documentaion](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLEncryptTOC.html) to enable SSL encryption for node-to-node and client-to-node.

I don't have `.pem` files that are assigned to `key`, `cert`, and `ca` as described in the referred post.

All files I got after following the datastax documentation were `gen_rootCa_cert.conf`, `rootCa.crt`, `rootCa.key`, `rootCa.srl`, `54.112.38.22.csr`, `54.112.38.22.crt_signed`, `54.112.38.22.jks`, `server-keystore.jks`, and `server-truststore.jks`.

Do I need to create other files such as those `.pem` files for `sslOptions` to work?

If the existent files are all I need, which file should be assigned to which option?

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var sslOptions = {
  key : fs.readFileSync("./rootCa.key"),
  cert : fs.readFileSync("./rootCa.crt")
};
```